# Text value transferring tool?

Tags: python, transfer

I have a big problem regarding text movements. It is a small but bad issue that could be fixed with the help of a little programm.

It's about transferring number values from a text based ".bvh" file to another text file with a different structure.

The structure of a bvh file is as follows:

```
HIERARCHY
ROOT AllRoot
{
    OFFSET 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
    CHANNELS 6 Xposition Yposition Zposition Xrotation Yrotation Zrotation
    JOINT Body
    {
        OFFSET 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
        CHANNELS 6 Xposition Yposition Zposition Xrotation Yrotation Zrotation
        JOINT Head
        {
            OFFSET 0.000000 200.000000 -0.000009
            CHANNELS 6 Xposition Yposition Zposition Xrotation Yrotation Zrotation
            End Site
            {
                OFFSET 0.000000 80.000000 1.000000
            }
        }
        JOINT Tail
        {
            OFFSET -200.000000 0.000000 0.000000
            CHANNELS 6 Xposition Yposition Zposition Xrotation Yrotation Zrotation
            End Site
            {
                OFFSET 0.000000 80.000000 1.000000
            }
        }
    }
}
MOTION
Frames: 5
Frame Time: 0.041667
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 51.851856 0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000004 200.000000 -0.000009 -0.015106 11.665742 0.147871 -199.999985 0.562456 -44.996483 -0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 148.148163 0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000 199.999985 -0.000009 -0.140997 33.330387 0.471003 -199.999985 1.124912 -89.992966 -0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 200.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 -0.000015 199.999985 -0.000009 -0.296590 44.995524 0.716104 -200.000000 -1.124912 89.992966 -0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 200.000000 1.874853 -149.988266 -0.000000 44.995524 0.716104 0.000030 199.999985 -0.000024 -0.058999 22.498145 0.296633 -199.999969 1.124912 -89.992966 0.000000 -0.000002 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 200.000000 3.749707 -299.976562 -90.000000 89.283837 90.000201 0.000009 199.999985 -0.000026 -0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 -199.999985 -1.124912 89.992928 -0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

And the structure of the text file, where the values have to be transferred to look like this:

```
BCK Header
Loop Flags: 1
Angle Multiplier: 2
Animation Length: 4

Joint 0
X Scale: [0,1.0,0]
X Rotation: [0,0,0]
X Translation: [0,0.0,0]
Y Scale: [0,1.0,0]
Y Rotation: [0,0,0]
Y Translation: [0,0.0,0]
Z Scale: [0,1.0,0]
Z Rotation: [0,0,0]
Z Translation: [0,0.0,0]

Joint 1
X Scale: [0,1.0,0]
X Rotation: [0,16384,0] [1,16384,0] [2,16384,0] [3,16384,0] [4,12288,0]
X Translation: [0,51.85185600000000,0] [1,148.14816300000000,0] [2,200.00000000000000,0] [3,200.00000000000000,0] [4,200.00000000000000,0]
Y Scale: [0,1.0,0]
Y Rotation: [0,16384,0] [1,16384,0] [2,16384,0] [3,18431,0] [4,20479,0]
Y Translation: [0,0.00000000000000,0] [1,0.00000000000000,0] [2,0.00000000000000,0] [3,1.87485300000000,0] [4,3.74970700000000,0]
Z Scale: [0,1.0,0]
Z Rotation: [0,16384,0] [1,16384,0] [2,16384,0] [3,16384,0] [4,20479,0]
Z Translation: [0,0.00000000000000,0] [1,0.00000000000000,0] [2,0.00000000000000,0] [3,-149.98826600000000,0] [4,-299.97656200000000,0]

Joint 2
X Scale: [0,1.0,0]
X Rotation: [0,0,0]
X Translation: [0,-0.00000400000000,0] [1,0.00000000000000,0] [2,-0.00001500000000,0] [3,0.00003000000000,0] [4,0.00000900000000,0]
Y Scale: [0,1.0,0]
Y Rotation: [0,16914,0] [1,17900,0] [2,18431,0] [3,17407,0] [4,16384,0]
Y Translation: [0,200.00000000000000,0] [1,199.99998500000000,0] [2,199.99998500000000,0] [3,199.99998500000000,0] [4,199.99998500000000,0]
Z Scale: [0,1.0,0]
Z Rotation: [0,0,0]
Z Translation: [0,-0.00000900000000,0] [1,-0.00000900000000,0] [2,-0.00000900000000,0] [3,0.00002400000000,0] [4,0.00002600000000,0]

Joint 3
X Scale: [0,1.0,0]
X Rotation: [0,0,0]
X Translation: [0,-199.99998500000000,0] [1,-199.99998500000000,0] [2,-200.00000000000000,0] [3,1.12491200000000,0] [4,-1.12491200000000,0]
Y Scale: [0,1.0,0]
Y Rotation: [0,0,0]
Y Translation: [0,0.56245600000000,0] [1,1.12491200000000,0] [2,-1.12491200000000,0] [3,199.99998500000000,0] [4,199.99998500000000,0]
Z Scale: [0,1.0,0]
Z Rotation: [0,0,0]
Z Translation: [0,-44.99648300000000,0] [1,-89.99296600000000,0] [2,89.99296600000000,0] [3,-89.99296600000000,0] [4,89.99292800000000,0]
```

Basically the values that have to be transferred are all the number values after the "Frame Time" text. Each row represent a frame and these values are position and rotation values. The values from a frame are in the order shown next to the "CHANNELS X" text in the header. It's usually: Xposition Yposition Zposition Xrotation Yrotation Zrotation.

The Translation values in the resulting text file should show each frame in these [] brackets: [FrameNumber,Value,0] (The last value is unimportant and can stay at 0)
What's important, the "translation" values always need a dot with exactly 14 numbers after it (for example 33.25000000000000).
So basically, when the first 3 frames of the first Joint look like this:

```
5.000000 -13.250000 8.400000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
10.000000 -23.250000 18.400000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
15.000000 -33.250000 28.400000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

Then in the resulting text file it should look like this:

```
Joint 0
X Scale: [0,1.0,0]
X Rotation: [0,0,0]
X Translation: [0,5.00000000000000,0] [1,10.00000000000000,0] [2,15.00000000000000,0]
Y Scale: [0,1.0,0]
Y Rotation: [0,0,0]
Y Translation: [0,-13.25000000000000,0] [1,-23.25000000000000,0] [2,-33.25000000000000,0]
Z Scale: [0,1.0,0]
Z Rotation: [0,0,0]
Z Translation: [0,8.40000000000000,0] [1,18.40000000000000,0] [2,28.40000000000000,0]
```

The rotation values are a bit tricky as they need a small calculation, but i already wrote a python script that can do this, but that's all what i could do so far:

```
ROTATION = float( input('Enter rotation of a bvh file (example: "44.995524") ') )

#CHECK: [- Degree] or [+ Degree] or [0°]

# [0°]
if(ROTATION == 0):              
    RESULT = 16384

# [+ Degree]
if(ROTATION > 0):               
    ROTATION = ROTATION * 45.50972222222222
    ROTATION = 16383.5 + ROTATION
    RESULT = round(ROTATION)

# [- Degree]
if(ROTATION < 0):       
    ROTATION = -1 * ROTATION    # [-] becomes [+]
    ROTATION = ROTATION * 45.50972222222222
    ROTATION = 16383.5 - ROTATION
    RESULT = round(ROTATION)

print("Result: ")
print(RESULT)
```

The only values that needs to be transferred from the .bvh file are the frame values.

Comment: Hi Lou, that's some pretty complicated behavior there! It'll be much easier to answer if you can narrow the scope on this a bit? What's the specific item you're struggling with? You seem to be doing alright so far!

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). This is not a code-writing service nor a discussion forum. If you need to understand the problem specification, you should ask the person who posed it. If you have a question about how to write the code, then you need to try to write the code and then ask a specific question regarding your attempt, explaining exactly what happened, exactly what was supposed to happen and how that is different.

Comment: Hi, so basically all i want is to transport text values in a different text file with a different structure. All the values after the "Frame Time" text have to be put into brackets. I just don't exactly know how to write a python script like this. It has to count the number of "joints" and "frames" so that it knows how many values it needs to pick and transfer to the resulting text file.